# error in pagination if no records in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

so if my offset is 0 i get a negative result like

```
var_dump($offset);
var_dump($per_page);
var_dump($uid);

float(-10) 
int(10) 
int(4)
```

and my code is

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applied WHERE memberID = :memberID";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $total = $stmt->fetchColumn();    

$pages = ceil($total / $per_page);

$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
'options' => array(
'default'   => 1,
'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM applied WHERE memberID = :memberID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :per_page OFFSET :offset";

         $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bindParam(':per_page', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

would this be a solution

```
$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; 
if($offset < 0){
$offset = 10;
}
```

or someone here could show me a better way to deal with this issue

appreciate your help

Comment: Rather silly question but this code implies that your pages are 0 based but your assumption is that they're 1 based. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the abs function of PHP to always make sure your offset is a positive number.

```
$offset = abs(($page - 1)  * $per_page);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that you'd always get the 2nd page even if `$page = 0`?

Comment: According to the author the value was -10 not zero so it should correct the problem he is having.

Comment: If `$page = 0` then `($page-1)*$per_page = -10` which is the root of the problem. Your solution would make it so `abs($page-1)*$per_page=10` which would offset the results by 10 and effectively get the 2nd page of results when in fact the 1st one is requested

Comment: Lets wait for the original poster to respond. My solution was based on his question which showed the offset value being -10 when he wanted it to be 10.

Comment: guys all i wanted was a proper fix to my code if you guys have some more better solution could really help me, i just don't want to get any errors in the future is all i wanted :)

Comment: @apokryfos what do you suggest then?

Comment: guys if i echo $offset = abs(($page - 1)  * $per_page); i get value as 1

Comment: Which is what you wanted I believe johram pong

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applied WHERE memberID = :memberID";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $total = $stmt->fetchColumn();    

$pages = ceil($total / $per_page);

$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
'options' => array(
'default'   => 1,
'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM applied WHERE memberID = :memberID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :per_page".($offset>0?" OFFSET :offset":"");

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':per_page', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
if ($offset > 0) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
$stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: get the following error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number'

Comment: Weird. That shouldn't happen.

Comment: thats what mate, i am getting strange errors on godaddy web host

Comment: appreciate your help too mate